# What is the idiomatic way to write a UNIX pipeline filter in F#?

Tags: f#

what is the idiomatic way in F# for writing little UNIX command-line tools that process lines from `stdin` and write to `stdout`? I am a F# newbie, and have assembled the pattern below from various SO posts which works, but is there a more elegant/more idiomatic way for that last expression?

```
#!/usr/bin/fsharpi --exec

let transform (line : string) =
    SOME_FUNCTION_OF line  // line transformation goes here

// is there a more idiomatic way of writing this:
Seq.initInfinite(fun _ -> System.Console.In.ReadLine())
    |> Seq.takeWhile(fun line -> line <> null)
    |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn  "%s" (transform x))
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably get lots of answers to this because it's really about personal style, and everybody likes to show their preferred way of doing things :) Here's my two cents:

1. Alias long ugly external API calls.
2. When passing a lambda, collapse the longer "(fun x ->" syntax (if possible, and if it doesn't affect readability).
3. Try to avoid doing more than performing a side effect in iter(). Doing the mapping in a separate step improves readability.

So,

```
let readLine = Console.In.ReadLine
let notEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not

Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> readLine())
|> Seq.takeWhile notEmpty
|> Seq.map transform
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```